# Fredholm equation of the second kind with non-compact integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

Given the linear integral of Fredholm type with symmetric kernel for $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\lambda \int_0^\infty \frac{dt\,f(t)}{1+x+t}.
\end{equation}
The radius of convergence in $\lambda$ should be $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

What is the solution? I'm in particular interested in the point $f(0)$, which has in the $\lambda$ expansion values of the Riemann Zeta function at even positive integers.